# providerName="MSSQL" changes to providerName="SQLite" when publishing

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, web-config, publishing

Sorry, I'm super new to Visual Studio and Azure and C#, but I searched the forums and could not find an answer for this. In Visual Studio in my Web.config file I have the providerName set as "=MSSQL", but when I publish it the Web.config file on the server changes it to "=SQLite" which breaks my site. I can go in and manually change it in Azure and everything works great, but why is it not publishing correctly in the first place? Why does it change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file "parameters.xml" the defaultValue for the database was set to "SQLite". I changed that to "MSSQL" and it seems to be fine now.